# Android Hybrid App - Status Bar Now Hidden (by default?)

Tags: android, statusbar

I have just updated an Android hybrid app (HTML5 with Java Wrapper) from Android 23 to Android 27 and the status bar which was previously visible is now white with no icons visible.

I have not changed any of my single java module MainActivity, nor have I changed anything in the manifest. The only changes I have made are to the .app file and these were limited to changes to the linked library version numbers now linking to support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 and support:design:27.1.1 and also changes to the compile and build versions (from 23 to 27).

Please could someone let me know how to make the status bar visible again.

My test phone is running Android 6 if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: for clarification, can you show us your activity styles?

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the theme style now defaulting to Dark, which makes the status bar icons white and hence invisible on my white app background. By adding the line of code below to my mainActivity, the status bar icons reappear as they are now black (or very dark grey) against white.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) mWebView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

The same cure can be made in res/values/styles.xml by setting

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
```